# Dynamic variables use with file upload as in the body of the HTTP request JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am uploading a file [.xml] to be the body of the POSt HTTP request. But the file has a variable ${TEVAM} whose value is being fetched from the previous request and being assigned.

But the value is not being replaced.

What should I use here?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the nested variables resolved you need to use [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) as a wrapper for i.e. [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) like:

```
${__eval(${__FileToString(test.xml,,)})}
```

[image: JMeter Upload Resolve Variables In a File]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

Comment: How do I give the path location for this file?

Comment: I have the following data in the file test.xml: {
"esn":"${TEVESN}"
}

Comment: i have a csv file which has the TEVESN and value as 3011117467. Its not replacing this variable before sending to the backend